# How to factor a polynomial with a complex term?

Tags: polynomials, complex-numbers, factoring

I'm a little bit confused on how to factor an expression containing a complex number . To elucidate my concerns I shall give an example ;

Say we have $x^4-z$, where z is a complex number can we factor this as ,

$x^4-z=(x+i\sqrt[4]{z})(x-i\sqrt[4]{z})(x+\sqrt[4]{z})(x-\sqrt[4]{z})$ ?

Edit: I have edited this post to fix my mistake, originally i had put z where $\sqrt[4]{z}$ should have been

Comment: Your factorization is that of $x^4-z^4=(x+iz)(x-iz)(x+z)(x-z)$.

Comment: Have you tried expanding the RHS?

Comment: If $z=c^4$, then you can replace $z$ in the RHS with $c$ to get a correct factorization.

Comment: sorry guys, silly little mistake i made ther, thats from not checking my work after writing it :/ . I've edited it now. I was just mainly worried that there was some different rules for factorization when Z was complex. But does my edit now give the correct factorisation ?

Comment: Factorization rules are the same. But you can't reliably use the $\sqrt{}$ sign for complex numbers. There are lots of questions and answers on this site that explain why.

Comment: @EthanBolker Yes the $\sqrt[4]{}$ had worried me, I was actually a little unclear in my previous comment , I meant can we factor using $ \sqrt[4]{z}$. Would you perhaps be able to link me to a question on the site which explains how to factor a problem such as mine ?

Comment: You mean to ask how to write out $\sqrt[4]{a+bi}$? The easiest approach is to convert to polar and use [Euler's formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%27s_formula).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The expression $\sqrt[4]{z}$ is at best ambiguous, at worst meaningless.

To factor 
$$
x^4 - z
$$
in the complex numbers you need to find the four fourth roots of $z$. The most straightforward way to do that is to find one of them by finding the fourth root of the modulus and one fourth of the argument. (This is what @SimplyBeautifulArt says in his comment.) For example, one fourth root of $i$ is 
$$
w = e^{\pi/8} = \cos(\pi/8) + i \sin(\pi/8).
$$
Then you find all four fourth roots by multiplying by the fourth roots of $1$. Those are $\pm 1$ and $\pm i$.

So (as @deyore comments)
$$
x^4 - i = (x-w)(x+w)(x-iw)(x+iw).
$$

No one of those fourth roots is reliably singled out by $\sqrt[4]{i}$ so you should avoid that notation. (Sometimes by convention the fourth root in the first quadrant could be so labelled, but please don't.)